# lamport pf2.sty and hide/show parts of nested enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I am currently getting acquainted with Leslie Lamports pf2.sty
(http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/latex/latex.html).

Which unfortunately is not on CTAN.

It intents to encourage a certain proof style, which Lamport calls 
hierarchical proof.
A proof looks then a lot as nested enumerate environments

The pf2.sty package itself is not so comfortable and most of its
features can be achieved by using the enumitem package.

However there is one useful feature which I don't know how to implement
in vanilla latex, namely hide/show parts of the nested proofs.

Here is an example (presuming you have pf.sty

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{pf2}
 \begin{document}
 \pfhidelevel{1}
 \begin{proof}
   \step{item:test-lamport2:1b}{Text of step 1.}
   \begin{proof}
     \step{label-1.1}{Text of substep 1} 
      \begin{proof}
        \pf\ Paragraph proof using results in \stepref{label-1.1} .~\qed
      \end{proof}
     \step{label-2.1}{Text of substep 2}
    \end{proof}
    \step{label-2.2}{Text of step 2} 
  \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

so only text of step 1 and 2 are displayed after compiling, if I chose 
\pfhidelevel{2}, then also the next level will be shown etc.

Now to my enumitem solution

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \setenumerate[1]{label=$\langle$1$\rangle$\arabic*., ref=$\langle$1$\rangle$\arabic*}
 \setenumerate[2]{label=$\langle$2$\rangle$\arabic*., ref=$\langle$1$\rangle$ref=\arabic*}
 \begin{document}


  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{item:test-lamport2:1b}{Text of step 1.}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \label{item:solution-enumitem:1} Text of substep 1
       \begin{enumerate}
         \item[\textsc{PROOF}] Paragraph proof using results in
         \ref{item:solution-enumitem:1}. $\blacksquare$
       \end{enumerate}
      \item \label{label-2.1}{Text of substep 2}
     \end{enumerate}
     \item \label{label-2.2}{Text of step 2} 
   \end{enumerate}
 \end{document}
```

Uwe Brauer

Comment: the implementation of `\pfhidelevel ` is pretty simple but it would be easier to answer if you provided a full document using pf2 so it can be tested and a second document with your proposed `enumitem` markup (but without the hiding) so we just need to test adding the hide level feature.

Comment: I seem unable to add the required text. It will be malformed. any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \setenumerate[1]{label=$\langle$1$\rangle$\arabic*., ref=$\langle$1$\rangle$\arabic*}
 \setenumerate[2]{label=$\langle$2$\rangle$\arabic*., ref=$\langle$1$\rangle$ref=\arabic*}

\newcount\pflevel
\newcommand\pfhidelevel[1]{\pflevel=#1\relax}
\let\zzenumerate\enumerate
\makeatletter
\def\enumerate{%
\ifnum\pflevel=\@enumdepth
\setbox0\vbox\bgroup\begingroup\aftergroup\egroup\aftergroup\endgroup
\fi
\zzenumerate}
 \begin{document}

00000

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{item:test-lamport2:1b}{Text of step 1.}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \label{item:solution-enumitem:1} Text of substep 1
       \begin{enumerate}
         \item[\textsc{PROOF}] Paragraph proof using results in
         \ref{item:solution-enumitem:1}. $\blacksquare$
       \end{enumerate}
      \item \label{label-2.1}{Text of substep 2}
     \end{enumerate}
     \item \label{label-2.2}{Text of step 2} 
   \end{enumerate}

111111


\pfhidelevel{1}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{item:test-lamport2:1b}{Text of step 1.}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \label{item:solution-enumitem:1} Text of substep 1
       \begin{enumerate}
         \item[\textsc{PROOF}] Paragraph proof using results in
         \ref{item:solution-enumitem:1}. $\blacksquare$
       \end{enumerate}
      \item \label{label-2.1}{Text of substep 2}
     \end{enumerate}
     \item \label{label-2.2}{Text of step 2} 
   \end{enumerate}



2222222


\pfhidelevel{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{item:test-lamport2:1b}{Text of step 1.}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \label{item:solution-enumitem:1} Text of substep 1
       \begin{enumerate}
         \item[\textsc{PROOF}] Paragraph proof using results in
         \ref{item:solution-enumitem:1}. $\blacksquare$
       \end{enumerate}
      \item \label{label-2.1}{Text of substep 2}
     \end{enumerate}
     \item \label{label-2.2}{Text of step 2} 
   \end{enumerate}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: great, thanks. the only thing: maybe it should be called showlevel, not hidehavel, because as higher the number is chosen as more  is shown, but this is just nitpicking. thanks again.