# enumitem: turn on and off label setting locally using a variable?

Tags: enumitem

Three years ago, David Carlisle provided a code snipped in tex.stackexchange:

[lamport pf2.sty and hide/show parts of nested enumerate environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443326/lamport-pf2-sty-and-hide-show-parts-of-nested-enumerate-environment?noredirect=1#comment1112761_443326)

That greatly helped me to use a simplified version of Leslie Lamports
pf2.sty, created
to deal with what Leslie Lamport calls structured proofs

https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/proof.pdf
http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/latex/pf2.pdf
http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/latex/latex.html

My style looks basically like this

```
 \setenumerate[1]{label=$\langle$1$\rangle$\arabic*., ref=$\langle$1$\rangle$\arabic*}
 \setenumerate[2]{label=$\langle$2$\rangle$\arabic*., ref=$\langle$2$\rangle$\arabic*}
 \setenumerate[3]{label=$\langle$3$\rangle$\arabic*., ref=$\langle$3$\rangle$\arabic*}
 \setenumerate[4]{label=$\langle$4$\rangle$\arabic*., ref=$\langle$4$\rangle$\arabic*}
 \setenumerate[5]{label=$\langle$5$\rangle$\arabic*., ref=$\langle$5$\rangle$\arabic*}
```

I did not, however, want to have a new environment (using the newlist command, since I am a die hard user of GNU emacs together with AucTex, so in order to have a convient way to insert such a new environment, I had to write some additional lisp code that I tried to avoid)

However I face a stupid problem, if I load this style into any latex document, then by construction, every enumerate environment uses that Lamport style of labeling.

In order to have a more standard labeling scheme I just write each time

```
  \end{enumerate}
```

So the question is can I have a new variable that toggle the configuration of my style on and off in a buffer, so that I can switch between between Lamport's style and the vanilla behaviour.

Comment: Why not use `\SetEnumitemKey{ h key i }{ h replacement i }` to define your own keys to `enumerate`, see the enumitem manual section 3.11.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's better to make your intentions clear and use the appropriate environment when needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\SetEnumitemKey{lamport}{
  label=$\langle$\the\@enumdepth$\rangle$\arabic*.,
  ref=$\langle$\the\@enumdepth$\rangle$\arabic*,
  nosep
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[lamport]
\item X
\item Xa
      \begin{enumerate}[lamport]
      \item Y
      \item Ya
            \begin{enumerate}[lamport]
            \item Z
            \item Za
                  \begin{enumerate}[lamport]
                  \item inner
                  \end{enumerate}
            \end{enumerate}
       \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, define an environment in which the changes apply.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{lamport}{%
  \setenumerate{
    label=$\langle$\the\@enumdepth$\rangle$\arabic*.,
    ref=$\langle$\the\@enumdepth$\rangle$\arabic*,
    nosep
  }
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lamport}
\begin{enumerate}
\item X
\item Xa
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Y
      \item Ya
            \begin{enumerate}
            \item Z
            \item Za
                  \begin{enumerate}
                  \item inner
                  \end{enumerate}
            \end{enumerate}
       \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{lamport}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Standard 1
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Standard 2
            \begin{enumerate}
            \item Standard 3
            \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi 
I forgot to thank you, the second solution is very very helpful!

Comment: HI, meanwhile I found out that I might need to enhance the enumerate deepth. (and have to see whether this still can be displayed nicely)
https://texblog.org/2011/10/10/increase-enumerate-itemize-depth-with-enumitem/
there is a solution but I failed to apply it to the specific lamport environment you proposed.
So is it possible, to enhance the deepth level in this environment?
Uwe Brauer

Comment: @UweBrauer Sorry, but this is not really clear. Please, open a new followup question.

Comment: Hi, Ok, but my followup question do you mean to start a new question? I am asking because I don't see an option for followup question?

Comment: @UweBrauer Yes, a new question, possibly citing this thread.

Comment: Ok I just did this right now.

Comment: To be precise the link for the new question is here
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694284/lamport-proof-style-enumitem-enhance-nesting-level