# Lamport proof style, enumitem, enhance nesting level

Tags: enumerate

Two years ago user egreg posted a nice solution,

[enumitem: turn on and off label setting locally using a variable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620595/enumitem-turn-on-and-off-label-setting-locally-using-a-variable/620622?noredirect=1#comment1723114_620622)
which looks like this

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{lamport}{%
  \setenumerate{
    label=$\langle$\the\@enumdepth$\rangle$\arabic*.,
    ref=$\langle$\the\@enumdepth$\rangle$\arabic*,
    nosep
  }
}{}
\makeatother
```

that allows to mimic Lamports proof style

https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/proof.pdf http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/latex/pf2.pdf http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/latex/latex.html

However it only allows 4 nesting level (which is the LaTeX default)

so the following example would not work:

```
\begin{lamport}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{item:nest2:1}
    The theorem  follows from Lemma 1\\
    \textsc{Proof of Lemma 1:}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \label{item:nest2:2}
      Lemma 1 follows from Lemma 2\\
      \textsc{Proof of Lemma 2:}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{item:nest2:4}
        Lemma 2 follows from  Lemma 3\\
        \textsc{Proof of Lemma 3:}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item \label{item:nest2:5}
          Lemma 3 follows from Lemma 4\\
          \textsc{Proof of Lemma 4}
          \begin{enumerate}
            \item \label{item:nest2:6}
            Lemma 4 follows from Lemma 5
          \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lamport}
```

so in short how could the nesting level enhanced say to at least 10 levels (whether this is a good idea, is another matter, but I rather would prefer to have the possiblity and if needed not use it

thanks
Uwe Brauer

Answer (score 1):

Just add `\renewlist{enumerate}{enumerate}{<depth>}` to the definition. Here I chose 9. Also, note that `\setenumerate` (and `\setitemize` and `\setdescription`) have been deprecated in favor of `\setlist[<envname>]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{lamport}{%
  \renewlist{enumerate}{enumerate}{9}
  \setlist[enumerate]{
    label=$\langle$\the\@enumdepth$\rangle$\arabic*.,
    ref=$\langle$\the\@enumdepth$\rangle$\arabic*,
    nosep
  }
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lamport}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{item:nest2:1}
    The theorem follows from Lemma 1\\
    \textsc{Proof of Lemma 1:}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \label{item:nest2:2}
      Lemma 1 follows from Lemma 2\\
      \textsc{Proof of Lemma 2:}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{item:nest2:4}
        Lemma 2 follows from  Lemma 3\\
        \textsc{Proof of Lemma 3:}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item \label{item:nest2:5}
          Lemma 3 follows from Lemma 4\\
          \textsc{Proof of Lemma 4:}
          \begin{enumerate}
            \item \label{item:nest2:6}
            Lemma 4 follows from Lemma 5\\
            \textsc{Proof of Lemma 5:}
            \begin{enumerate}
              \item \label{item:nest2:7}
              Lemma 5 follows from Lemma 6\\
              \textsc{Proof of Lemma 6:} 
            \end{enumerate}
          \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lamport}

\end{document}
```

[image: enumerate]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, that was precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: Hi  now there is a problem, concerning hiding/showing level
I posted a followup question
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694383/lamport-proof-style-enhance-nesting-level-but-still-hide-parts-of-it
thanks