# Lamport proof style,enhance nesting level but (still) hide parts of it

Tags: enumitem

yesterday user mbert [Lamport proof style, enumitem, enhance nesting level](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694284/lamport-proof-style-enumitem-enhance-nesting-level/694299#694299)
provided a nice enhancement, for Lamport style proofs, enhancing the enumerate depth.
His solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{lamport}{%
  \renewlist{enumerate}{enumerate}{9}
  \setlist[enumerate]{
    label=$\langle$\the\@enumdepth$\rangle$\arabic*.,
    ref=$\langle$\the\@enumdepth$\rangle$\arabic*,
    nosep
  }
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lamport}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{item:nest2:1}
    The theorem follows from Lemma 1\\
    \textsc{Proof of Lemma 1:}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \label{item:nest2:2}
      Lemma 1 follows from Lemma 2\\
      \textsc{Proof of Lemma 2:}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{item:nest2:4}
        Lemma 2 follows from  Lemma 3\\
        \textsc{Proof of Lemma 3:}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item \label{item:nest2:5}
          Lemma 3 follows from Lemma 4\\
          \textsc{Proof of Lemma 4:}
          \begin{enumerate}
            \item \label{item:nest2:6}
            Lemma 4 follows from Lemma 5\\
            \textsc{Proof of Lemma 5:}
            \begin{enumerate}
              \item \label{item:nest2:7}
              Lemma 5 follows from Lemma 6\\
              \textsc{Proof of Lemma 6:} 
            \end{enumerate}
          \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lamport}
```

However  David Carlisle provided a solution
[lamport pf2.sty and hide/show parts of nested enumerate environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443326/lamport-pf2-sty-and-hide-show-parts-of-nested-enumerate-environment?noredirect=1#comment1112761_443326)
for hiding and showing the enumeration level for my old code

```
\def\labelenumi{\theenumi}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{lamport}{%
  \setenumerate{
    label=$\langle$\the\@enumdepth$\rangle$\arabic*.,
    ref=$\langle$\the\@enumdepth$\rangle$\arabic*,
    nosep,
     topsep=0pt,
     itemsep=1pt,
     partopsep=1ex,
     parsep=2ex
  }
}{}
\makeatother
```

his solution was/is

```
\newcount\pflevel
\newcommand\pfshowlevel[1]{\pflevel=#1\relax}
\let\zzenumerate\enumerate
\makeatletter
\def\enumerate{%
\ifnum\pflevel=\@enumdepth
\setbox0\vbox\bgroup\begingroup\aftergroup\egroup\aftergroup\endgroup
\fi
\zzenumerate}
```

however that now does not work, with the enhanced enumerate depth.
any idea how show/hide levels for the new code?
thanks

Uwe Brauer